# Convert HTML to searchable PDF using PhantomJS / Node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I am generating PDF's server side with an HTML template that gets completed with data from the client and server.  The code below works, but:
1) The PDF file is 5x bigger than when it is 'Saved as PDF' on the client side.
2) The PDF is not searchable.

I am assuming both of these problems stem from PhantomJS generating a raster vs. vector based PDF.  What should I do differently (hoping I am just missing an PhantomJS option or two...)??

```
    var phantom = require('phantom');

    req.body['invoicenumber'] = 15010001;
    phantom.create(function(ph){
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
            page.set('paperSize', { format: 'Letter',orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' });
            page.open("html/template.html", function(status) {
                page.evaluate(function(data) {
                    $(function() { populate(data); });
                    },function() {
                        var quotenumber
                        page.render('quotes/'+req.body['invoicenumber']+'.pdf', function(){
                            ph.exit();
                            res.send(req.body['invoicenumber']+'.pdf');
                    });
                },req.body); 
            });     
        });
    })
```

**MINOR UPDATE:** Increasing the margin so the page is not scaled up reduces the file size, but still 2.5x the client side 'Save as PDF'...

Comment: In order to be searchable, text has to be made as Text, not as image, and not as vector graphic (that would be outlined text).

Comment: When I have scanned documents in the past, 'raster to vector' was used to create a searchable document.  If 'outlined text' is the correct term in this case, I stand corrected.

Comment: In fact, if you call it "raster-to-vector", and it creates searchable text, then everything is fine. In this case, the converter actually does OCR (Optical Character Recognition), and that's what we need. OCR creates Text, whereas all a "simple" vectorization does is turn shapes into outlined vector objects, and if that happens, you have vector, but text has not been recognized as such. In other words, no need to feel to stand corrected…

Comment: Why not to save the page as `html` and only then convert it to `pdf`? (e.g. with `html2pdf`)

Comment: If possible, I would consider switching to using wkhtmltopdf, as so far in my experience it can generate the smallest pdf's out of the tools I have tested so far. I have not used it, but there is a [Node.is wrapper for wkhtmltopdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf). The output contains actual text, rather than raster/vector output. As it is based on webkit, it's possible to run Javascript to modify (and pretty much anything one can do in a browser) the html prior to rendering. I haven't added it as an answer as it does not use PhantomJS.

Comment: If it solves my issue, it doesn't matter what module(s) it uses (as long as it can run on all the major OS's)...  I briefly played around with wkhtmltopdf in node.js, but didn't see a way to process my template the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In the html template try using any of these header tags (h1,h2...h6) to wrap your content. The content inside these headers tags will be rendered as text in the generated pdf. Hence it should be searchable. This will also reduce good amount of pdf file size. Not sure why div, p, table etc tags are rendered as image in the pdf.